# How can I redirect requests for a site in IIS to a different external server?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis, reverse-proxy

I am about to move my website away from IIS to a Linux VPS. Part of this involves updating zone records.

There will be some time from when I change my zone records to when they are propagated to client computers. So there will be requests to the IIS server for a domain which points to a different IP.

I would like to configure my server so when it receives a request to http://example.com/some/path, it transparently (or non-transparently) forwards the request to the new server. Please note that I cannot simply do a 302 redirect as the domain name is not changing, only the zone records for the domain name.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this in the past by creating a www2.whatever.com sub domain, which the new server will listen on *in addition* to www. The key is that it cannot be a redirect to www (otherwise you're back at square one).

After changing DNS to point www at the new server you change the old server to 302 redirect www to www2.

The result is that clients who get the updated DNS entry work as expected while those who get a cached entry get a temporary redirect to www2 (which is new and always pointed to the new server). Eventually their cache expires and their attempts to connect to www point at the new server.

After enough time has passed you could then 301 redirect www2 to www, but I think in most cases you'd be fine just deleting it.

### Alternatively

You could have all of your requests come in through a proxy. I use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com)'s free plan on all of my sites, and since all requests actually go through them, changing my sites' IP address really just changes an entry in their proxy. End users see the same IP addresses in DNS so the change is basically instant.

Comment: What if you cannot change the subdomain, as it is unique per customer? Is there any way to redirect `http://customer1.example.com/some/path` to the same URL on another server located on a different IP?

Comment: @Alph.Dev unfortunately no you wouldn't be able to use the same subdomain in both places unless you're proxying the requests (as in my second suggestion). Note that in my first, you are not _changing_ the sub-domain, just adding a second one. So you could add `www.customer1.example.com`. Note using any mthod with a different domain has concerns for SSL.

Comment: I want to let you know that I got this working using IIS Url Rewrite rules + Application Request Routing (ARR) module, all configured on the source server. So it is possible without having to change any part of the requested URL and without external proxy.

Comment: @Alph.Dev that's great news! I answered your comment taken in the context of the original question so I may have misunderstood the problem. Posting an answer on this question could be useful for other readers (and myself!).

Answer (score 0):

Install ARR - Application Request Routing - in IIS and then configure it. Finished.

IIS has this functionality for ages.

Comment: This doesn't work as the web server I am forwarding the request to only responds when you access it with the domain name, not the IP (it returns the wrong website).